# Any way to change the actual filename of an image from media manager?

Tags: plugins, media-library

The default WP media manager does not appear to offer the ability to change an image's filename.

Are there any plugins available that allow this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Media File Renamer](http://www.meow.fr/media-file-renamer).

Comment: Sweet! I'll give it a whirl.